# Getting "error TS2589" on GH Actions but works locally

Tags: typescript, next.js, github-actions, next-i18next

I am getting following error on GH actions:

```bash
error TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAUuh.png)

Locally the same command works.
[local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufaHy.png)

Error refers to the line:

```
const { t } = useTranslation()
```

I checked TS and node versions and they are equal both on GH actions and on my machine.

Comment: Please don't [upload images of errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Click on **Edit** and share the error as text.